# Adding points at score (Swift)

Tags: swift

I've got a problem with Swift. I want to make a simple (for testing) app that works so: every time you click on the button it the score will be from 0 to 1 to 2 etc.. (every time you click it will add up +1)

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    ourScore.text = "1"
}

@IBOutlet var ourScore: UILabel!
```

ourScore.text is currently 0 when you click on the button it will be 1 but how can I add every time on the button so it will adding +1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution with a variable

```
@IBOutlet var ourScore: UILabel!
var score = 0

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    ourScore.text = "\(++score)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this even though it's not particularly safe (forced unwrap could fail) :

Swift 1 :

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    ourScore.text = String(ourScore.text.toInt()! + 1)
}

@IBOutlet var ourScore: UILabel!
```

Swift 2 :

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    ourScore.text = String(Int(ourScore.text)! + 1)
}

@IBOutlet var ourScore: UILabel!
```

I'd highly suggest you store the score in an `Int` variable. That would be a cleaner solution.